# Javascript on scroll resize ID with a minimum value applied first

Tags: javascript

I have a element when if scrolled down I'm upscaling the element by a X value which works completely fine.

The issue is though the SCALE by default is 0 so as soon as it's applied it starts from 0 when I'd like it to be from 1.

I have then set a scroll max position of 200px and a max SCALE of 2.0 in the CSS with an important tag and that seems to work.

If anyone can assist with this issue your efforts will be super helpful.

```
function parallaxy()
{
offset2 = +(scrollVal * 0.009);

layer2.style.webkitTransform = "scale(" + offset2 + ")";
layer2.style.MozTransform = "scale(" + offset2 + ")";
layer2.style.msTransform = "scale(" + offset2 + ")";
layer2.style.OTransform = "scale(" + offset2 + ")";
layer2.style.transform = "scale(" + offset2 + ")";  

}
```

Comment: have you tried just setting `scale(1)` in the CSS?

Comment: Yes but unfortunately the JS will overright this value. Help!! Please. hehe

Comment: can you put together a jsfiddle with a full working example?

Comment: Sure, I have put this together but for some reason I dont see how to attach JS libraries: https://jsfiddle.net/65z8uedz/5/ need to include 
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js and maybe: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js

Comment: Here's a version w/ jquery attached.  https://jsfiddle.net/65z8uedz/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var body = document.body;
var container = document.getElementById("parallax");


var isTouchscreen;
var scrollVal = 1;
var offset2;
var maxoffset = 10;

var layer2 = document.getElementById("layer-2");


function setup() {
  /*var platform = navigator.platform.toLowerCase();
  var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
 
  if ( platform.indexOf('ipad') != -1  ||  platform.indexOf('iphone') != -1 ) 
  { 
   isTouchscreen = 1; 
   container.setAttribute("class", "touch");
   body.style.backgroundImage = 'none';
  }

  else if (platform.indexOf('win32') != -1 || platform.indexOf('linux') != -1)
  {
   isTouchscreen = 0;
       
   if ($.browser.webkit)
   {
    $.srSmoothscroll();
   }
  }
 
  else
  {
   isTouchscreen = 0;
  }*/

}

function parallaxy() {
  //var elem = document.getElementById("layer1");
  //elem.style.transform = "10px";
//console.log(scrollVal);
  offset2 = +(scrollVal * 0.01);
 if (offset2 > maxoffset) {
    offset2 = maxoffset;
  } else {
    offset2 = +(scrollVal * 0.01);
  }
  layer2.style.webkitTransform = "scale(" + offset2 + ")";
  layer2.style.MozTransform = "scale(" + offset2 + ")";
  layer2.style.msTransform = "scale(" + offset2 + ")";
  layer2.style.OTransform = "scale(" + offset2 + ")";
  layer2.style.transform = "scale(" + offset2 + ")";
  //console.log(offset2);

}

function scrollHandler(e) {
  scrollVal = Math.max(window.pageYOffset, 0)+100;
  console.log(offset2);

  /* UNCOMMENT THESE LINES TO ABORT PARALLAX STUFF */
  /*
   isTouchscreen = 1;
   container.setAttribute("class", "touch");
   body.style.backgroundImage = 'none';
  */

  if (isTouchscreen != 1) {
    parallaxy();
  }
}

body.onload = setup();
document.addEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler, false);
```

```css
#container .container {
  z-index: 999;
  position: relative;
}
#parallax {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 50px !important;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1080px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.parallax_layer {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
#container.touch .parallax_layer {
  position: absolute;
}
#layer-2 {
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1080px;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  -o-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}
#layer-2 {
  background: url("http://www.staples.co.uk/content/images/product/GenesisExtraLarge/45/56/asset.1714556.jpg") transparent center top no-repeat;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parallax">
  <div class="parallax_layer" id="layer-2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bud you have completely aced this, it works like a charm, thank you so much. Say for example I wanted to apply a max scale to say 2.0 how would I go about this? at present I have the following which I believe is just a hacky work around which would force a .MAX class with an important tag?

$(document).ready(function() {
var top = $('#layer-2').offset().top;
  $(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop(); 
 if (y >= 210) {  $('#layer-2').addClass('max'); }
    else { $('#layer-2').removeClass('max'); }
  });
});

Comment: see my edited answer, just added a maxoffset check.  be sure to accept as correct answer if this was helpful.

Comment: oh, and you don't need jQuery.  this is all pure javascript.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your efforts it's been a huge help, I have used your code but don't seem to be seeing any maximum offset rule apply unfortunately in the code, is there a typo?

Comment: Please ignore me, I see what I did wrong here, seriously this works like a charm. Your help has been incredible, I'll accept your answer now. Thanks again so much!